# How to clone existing component without editing created component (Window) in Extjs 4.1

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I define a `Source Window` like

```
Ext.define('MyWindow', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    title: 'Source Window',
    modal: true,
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    closable:false,
    tbar: [{    
        text:'hide',
        handler:function(){
            this.up('window').hide();
        }
    }],
    items: { 
        xtype: 'grid',
        border: false,
        columns: [{header: 'World'}],
        store: Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {})
    }
    });
```

And i remove all item of the window then add new item to it like

```
var w = new MyWindow();
tf = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Text', {
      name: 'name',
      fieldLabel: 'Name'
});
w.removeAll(true);
w.add(tf);
w.show();
w.hide();
```

Now I want to clone my Window (window added new item) like

```
Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
        text: 'Clone to new',
        visible: false,
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        handler: function() {
            var newWin;
            Ext.WindowManager.each(function(win) {
                newWin = win.cloneConfig();
                newWin.title = "Clone Window";
                newWin.show();
            });
        }
      });
```

But that's show `Source Window` ?? How to fix that
Here is my full code **http://jsfiddle.net/MKUSB/**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, because the `cloneConfig` clones just the config of the component and not its items. The items of the new window will come from the original window and in your case you have to remove the original items and then clone the new items of the component. My code clones always just one window, your code did it exponentially if you clicked more than once on the `Clone Window` button.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/ph5Zy/

Full code:

```
Ext.define('MyWindow', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    title: 'Source Window',
    modal: true,
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    closable:false,
    tbar: [{    
        text:'hide',
        handler:function(){
            this.up('window').hide();
        }
    }],
    items: { 
        xtype: 'grid',
        id: 'grid',
        border: false,
        columns: [{header: 'World'}],
        store: Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {})
    }
    });


    Ext.onReady(function () {
        // create new window with new item    
        var i = 1;
        var w = new MyWindow();
        tf = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Text', {
              name: 'name',
              fieldLabel: 'Name',
              id: 'tf'
        });
        w.removeAll(true);
        w.add(tf);
        w.show();
        w.hide();

        Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
            text: 'Show all',
            visible: false,
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            handler: function() {
                Ext.WindowManager.each(function(win) {
                    win.show();
                });
            }
        });

          Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
            text: 'Clone to new',
            visible: false,
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            handler: function() {
                var newWin = w.cloneConfig();
                newWin.remove('grid');
                newWin.add(w.getComponent('tf').cloneConfig());
                newWin.title = "Clone Window";
                newWin.show();
            }
          });
    });
```

Comment: have anyway to using `newWin.add(w.items.cloneConfig()) // fail` ? i don't want using add id to anyway ?

Comment: You can also use the w.getComponent(0).cloneConfig() with the default numeric item id of the component and then you don't have to add text id. This numeric item id always starts from 0.